# Finding distance between 2 geospatial location in aws neptune with opencypher query language

Tags: aws, cypher

I am working with amazon neptune and using openCypher query language and doing some stuff using notebook. I have latitude and longitude of 2 points and I want to calculate the distance between these 2 points. For the purpose I am using Haversine formula. However to do this it required trigonometric functions like sin and cos and seems that those are not supported yet with neptune and openCypher. I am stuck here as I will be heavily doing operations on location. Any alternate solution without using sin cos ?

Comment: If locations differences are small (small angle approximation) you can get by with taking deltas of x and y coordinates respectively. Maybe some approximation functions exist that are suitable for your use case?

Comment: Many functions I checked requires trigonometric methods such as cos sin etc. if you have something in mind that doesn’t requires trigonometric methods, can you please suggest?

Comment: Don't know if this helps, but there's an extension for postgres called AGE, which let's you create graphs using openCypher with SQL. They have many trigonometric functions, including [sin](https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/functions/trigonometric_functions.html#sin) and [cos](https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/functions/trigonometric_functions.html#cos)